# Best option to improve an aging gaming computer (low budget)?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, gaming

I'm coming to you because I need your helpful advices about my girlfriend's rig.
It's becoming really old and she won't be able to buy a whole new computer anytime soon.
As it's nearly it's birthday, I think it could be great to buy her some parts to relieve this aging hardware (I'm talking about her computer !) and allow her to play in slightly better conditions.

As of today, she's playing on a Full HD screen, and she's a Final Fantasy fan. She also plays games like Borderlands/2, Metro, ...

And now the issue :
- Motherboard : Asus M4A77D
- CPU : AMD Athlon II X4 635
- GPU : AMD Radeon HD 6850
- RAM : 7Go (mixed models, result of the death of modules replaced by what we had and never changed) : 2x2Go Crucial Ballistix PC-6400, 1x2Go + 1x1Go Kingston ValueRAM PC-5300
- Power output : Advance MTP-6500 (650W)

The question is : what would be the best option to improve gaming performances of her rig, with a budget of 220 - 280$ (200 - 250€), or slightly higher ? What parts to change primarily ?

Of course I know I'm not going to make her computer a bulletproof gaming rig and she won't be able to play with maxed out graphics.

I just want to make it a little bit better so she can play in better conditions. Cheapest parts (RAM, SSD, ...) can be bought later from time to time by herself.

Thank you very much for you advices !

Comment: Since this is asking for shopping recommendations, this will be closed.  You havent really explained what isnt performing well.

Comment: @Keltari I think they are looking for what components to upgrade first vs shopping recommendations for the individual components which would be different (?)

Comment: If you are planning to upgrade everything eventually, I would start with the motherboard and RAM first. It may not be the popular opinion here, but the motherboard is the part that gets outdated the fastest and is your foundation of your build.

Comment: Not only is this off-topic, but do **not** post the same question multiple times: http://superuser.com/questions/908162/primary-upgrade-of-this-aging-computer

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but I believe "how do I upgrade my computer incrementally?" is a valid question.  However, I would expect some response from the poster guiding us.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer b/c it really depends on current performance and price of available parts.

I'm assuming the OS is Vista or above in which case you can get the Windows Experience Index.  This can tell you where the performance issues are.  You also aren't saying anything about hard drive size/type or utilization.

I would actually consider looking for a barebones system at this pricepoint.  These typically come with case, motherboard, and processor.  Some will come with memory.  You can reuse some components (but you will likely have to reinstall the OS).

Aside from this, memory and vga are usually the most effective upgrades, IMHO.  Next would be proc and HD.  But, you will quickly reach your limit on what you can do to this computer and it might be worth just putting the money in a new PC fund.  Check out newegg.com.  They usually have pretty good deals and they can help make sure you are getting the correct parts (very important).

Answer (score 0):

Find the bottlenecks and upgrade the biggest bottlenecks.

Is CPU 100% utilized?  Is video 100% utilized?  Is RAM maxed out and paging?  Are you utilizing dual memory channels and or is memory bandwidth a bottleneck?  Is the system having errors under load indicating lack of power?  Is PCIe bus bandwidth maxed out?

The answers to these questions are not necessarily easy to figure out, but they would be the key to knowing what to upgrade first.  Where components are maxed out and over utilized is where to upgrade.